# My Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 site is no longer loading the css

Tags: cms, css

I'm not sure what's caused it but my Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 site is no longer loading the css. I didn't make any changes to the site whatsoever, one day it was fine the next it had fallen over.

All of the css looks fine and checking it out with firebug everything looks to be pointing to the right place.

My site is http://www.geckoclothing.com/ and here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

http://1.9.0.1/
1.9.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reinstalled the theme, which has fixed it! No idea what broke the theme, as I haven't tried to update it or make any changes to it in months, but I'll now reinstall my css file and hopefully the site will be back to it's old self!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using ULTIMO Theme for the website. There may be many reasons for your CSS not being displayed.

1) The style is loaded properly, so the theme is properly included and setup. Still Step 1: Check in `System >> Configuration >> Design` if you have set ultimo as the theme properly.

2) Clear your Magento Caches

3) Have you used FTP to upload or update the `style.css` if yes, the file might have got corrupted. Please reupload the CSS.

4) There might be a problem with your files permission. Please ensure you skin folder has 644 and 755 permissions for files and folders

5) Goto `System >> Configuration >> UTLIMO >> Theme Design` and save the configuration. Do the same for Theme layout.

If all steps are followed, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Hi, thanks Dexter. I'm actually using the Fortis theme, which is also by Infortis, and everything seems to be set up correctly. All my folders within skin are set to 0755 and my files are set to 0644. I've tried re-uploading the styles.css to no avail. I've just saved the theme design configuration and still nothing.